# Fortran operator overloading based in C function

Tags: c, binding, fortran, operator-keyword, fortran-iso-c-binding

I want to expose a C++ class to Fortran. From various searches, I have seen that the most direct way is to use intermediate C functions.

My question is the following: considering a simple C struct describe below and a C function call `add`, how can I declare a Fortran module which would declare an associated Fortran derived type and use the `add` function for operator overloading ?

```
struct my_double{  double x; }

my_double add(const my_double*, const my_double*);
```

The (non working) solution I came up to is something like this:

```
module my_module
  use iso_c_binding
  type, bind(c) :: my_double
     real(c_double) :: x
  end type my_double
  interface operator (+)
    module procedure add
  end interface operator (+)
  interface
     type(my_double) function add (v1,v2) bind ( c )
       use iso_c_binding
       type (my_double), intent(in) :: v1,v2
       type (my_double)  :: v3
    end function add
  end interface
end module my_module
```

Does anyone have an advice on how to make this work ?

Comment: Welcome. Don't put any greetings or your name under your post, your name is appended automatically below. Also don't copy tags to the title. It is good to tell us in which way is the  example "non-working". Report any error messages you received.

Comment: You are just missing the import statement in the interface block, add it and it compiles fine.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the help. It indeed works well now.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate: I though the issue was related to C bindings, this is obviously not the case. Regards.